# Atom-Editor: Failed to load init.coffee - ERROR: reserved word 'function'

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

UPDATE: I found a solution/workaround for the problem. I renamed init.coffee to init.js because Atom also supports JavaScript. I would still like to know the cause of the problem. Is the script below not valid CoffeeScript or am I missing some dependence? I Installed Atom from the official Arch repositories.

For some reason my init.coffee cannot be loaded. The following code is from Atom's ["Composed" Commands](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#composed-commands) documentation:

```
atom.commands.add('atom-text-editor', 'custom:cut-line', function () {
  const editor = this.getModel();
  editor.selectLinesContainingCursors();
  editor.cutSelectedText();
});
```

Atom throws an error when it starts:

```
Failed to load /home/myname/.atom/init.coffee
reserved word 'function'
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug, my fault, or a result of out-of-date documentation. The error message isn't super helpful, since I already that "function" is a reserved word, even though I don't know a lot of Coffee/JavaScript.

I replaced `function` using `() -> {...}`, which resulted in the same error except this time for the reserved word `const`.

Finally, I tried defining a named function which I passed as an argument to `atom.commands.add()` and got the same error.

I'm on Linux. `atom --version` returns:

```
Atom    : 1.46.0
Electron: 4.2.12
Chrome  : 69.0.3497.128
Node    : 10.11.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove the solution summary from your question. SO isn't a message board or forum, it's like a reference book, with a question followed by solutions/answers. Solutions belong in answers _IF_ you solved the problem. See "[ask]" and all its linked pages along with the "[tour]". Also, when editing, don't use "Edit" or "Update" type tags. SO can show us exactly what changed if we need to know. Instead, simply incorporate the changed information into the original text as if it'd been there all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is the right direction - that code is JavaScript, not CoffeeScript.

It looks like the '["Composed" Commands](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#composed-commands)' documentation you referenced is using both JavaScript and CoffeeScript in their examples.

To convert from JavaScript:

```
atom.commands.add('atom-text-editor', 'custom:cut-line', function () {
  const editor = this.getModel();
  editor.selectLinesContainingCursors();
  editor.cutSelectedText();
});
```

to CoffeeScript:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'custom:cut-line',  () ->
  editor = @getModel()
  editor.selectLinesContainingCursors()
  editor.cutSelectedText()
```

- When calling a function with arguments, you can leave out the parenthesis `()`.
- `function` is removed in CoffeeScript, just use parenthesis and either a single `->` or double arrow `=>`, where a double arrow is the same as `.bind(this)`, so that would be incorrect here.
- No `const`/`let`/`var` keywords. Just defined the variable without them.
- `this.` can be replaced with `@`.
- Braces (`{}`) wrapping function definitions are optional.
- No semicolons.

If you want to learn CoffeeScript and help the community, you could fix the documentation yourself by forking, editing and making a pull request of the [repository](https://github.com/atom/flight-manual.atom.io/edit/master/content/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth.md).

Alternatively, you should report this error in the documentations in their repository as an [issue](https://github.com/atom/flight-manual.atom.io/issues).